# can not fetch relational data in watermelondb

Tags: javascript, reactjs, database, indexeddb, watermelondb

i have modles `Staff.js` and  `RanchOwner.js`.

Staff has One to many relation with ranch_owners , i want to fetch all ranch owners related to staff

`Staff.js`

```
import { Model } from '@nozbe/watermelondb';
import { field, date, relation } from '@nozbe/watermelondb/decorators';
import moment from 'moment';
// import { children, readonly, lazy } from '@nozbe/watermelondb/decorators';
export default class Staff extends Model {
  static table = 'staff';

  @field('id') id;
  @field('name') name;
  @field('email') email;
  @field('email_verified_at') emailVerifiedAt;
  @field('password') password;
  @field('fcm_token') fcmToken;
  @field('api_token') apiToken;
  @field('allowed_login') allowedLogin;
  @field('status') status;
  @field('admin') admin;
  @field('owner_id') ownerId;
  @field('role_id') role_id;
  @field('subrole_id') subroleId;
  @field('today_all_assigned_message_sent') todayAllAssignedMessageSent;
  @field('tomorrow_all_assigned_message_sent') tomorrowAllAssignedMessageSent;
  @field('today_all_gangs_assigned_message_sent') todayAllGangsAssignedMessageSent;
  @field('tomorrow_all_gangs_assigned_message_sent') tomorrowAllGangsAssignedMessageSent;
  @field('social_security_number') social_security_number;
  @field('phone_number') phoneNumber;
  @field('whatsapp') whatsapp;
  @field('photo') photo;
  @field('govt_id') govtId;
  @field('tax_id') taxId;
  @field('remember_token') rememberToken;
  @field('is_temporary') isTemporary;

  // @date('created_at') createdAt;
  @date('updated_at') updatedAt;
  @date('deleted_at') deletedAt;

  @field('warehouse') warehouse;
  @field('customer_id') customerId;
  @field('is_driver') isDriver;
  @field('online') online;
  @field('location_access') locationAccess;
  @field('qr_code') qrCode;
  @field('color') color;
  @field('belongs_to_staff') belongs_to_staff;
  @date('created_at') _created_at;
  

  get created_at() {
    return moment(this._created_at).format('DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss');
  }

  get role() {
    let role = '';
    switch (this.role_id) {
      case 1:
        role = 'agent';
        break;
      case 2:
        role = 'ranch_owner';
        break;
      case 3:
        role = 'worker';
        break;
      case 4:
        role = 'right_hand_man';
        break;
      case 5:
        role = 'independent_contractor';
        break;
      case 6:
        role = 'packaging_company';
        break;
      case 7:
        role = 'cutting_company';
        break;
      case 8:
        role = 'supervisor';
        break;
      case 9:
        role = 'gang_boss';
        break;

      case 10:
        role = 'driver';
        break;
      case 11:
        role = 'truck_assigner';
        break;
      case 12:
        role = 'company_worker';
        break;

      default:
        role = 'admin';
    }

    return role;
  }


  static associations = {
    ranch_owners: { type: 'has_many', foreignKey: 'staff_id' }
  };
  @relation('ranch_owners', 'staff_id') ranch_owners;

  
  // static associations = {
  //   ranch_owner: { type: 'belongs_to', key: 'staff_id' },
  // }

  // Relationships (if any)
  // Example:
  // @relation('another_table_name', 'foreign_key_column_name')
  // anotherTable;

  // Virtual fields (if any)
  // Example:
}
```

`RanchOwner.js`

```
import { Model } from '@nozbe/watermelondb';
import { field, relation, writer } from '@nozbe/watermelondb/decorators';
// import moment from 'moment';
// import { children, readonly, lazy } from '@nozbe/watermelondb/decorators';
export default class RanchOwner extends Model {
  static table = 'ranch_owners';

  @field('id') id;
  @field('tax_id') tax_id;
  @field('compliance_opinion') compliance_opinion;
  @field('address') address;
  @field('latitude') latitude;
  @field('longitude') longitude;
  @field('city') city;
  @field('hectares') hectares;
  @field('ranch_name') ranch_name;
  @field('person_id') person_id;
  @field('govt_id') govt_id;
  @field('general_manager') general_manager;
  @field('staff_id') staffId;
  @field('belongs_to_staff') belongs_to_staff;
  static associations = {
    staff: { type: 'belongs_to', key: 'staff_id' }
  };
  @relation('staff', 'staff_id') staff;

  @writer async updateRelationWithStaff(staff_id) {
    await this.batch(
      this.prepareUpdate((ranchOwner) => {
        
        ranchOwner.staffId = staff_id;
        console.log(ranchOwner.staffId )
      })
    );
  }

}
```

`Query`

```
 const initialData = await database.get('staff').query(Q.take(20), Q.sortBy('created_at', Q.desc)).fetch();
```

But when i try to fetch relational data it gives object like this but having no error

[image]

I tried to change the name of relationship and try to make it one-to-one relation aswell. but in any case i can not see related may be something is wrong with naming convention